# unable to load dll cvextern while using emgu cv for x86 platform

Tags: c#, python, emgucv, dllexport

> Requirement: Load a C# DLL(which uses Emgu.CV.World.dll for image
>   comparison) into python project and call function inside DLL with some
>   parameters.

I tried to export a DLL usig Emgu.CV.World.dll for image comparison. While compiling for "Any CPU" target, the DLL export was not working. After changed to x86 platform, DLL was loaded correctly from Python:

```
mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(self.libPath)
```

But while calling function inside the DLL:

```
ImageContentComparisonResult = mydll.CompareImageContent(self.OutputFile, self.OriginalFile)
```

throws the following exception:

> ```
> WindowsError: [Error -532462766] Windows Error 0xE0434352
> ```

Output from Visual Studio:

> ```
> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
> ```

After this, created a sample Emgu.CV project(GUI), got the same exception. There I got the exception details, like

> ```
> {"The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."}
> InnerException: {"Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
> ```

After copying the x86 and x64 DLLs for Emgu.CV to "bin\x86\Debug", it worked for the sample app, but for non GUI C# project, it's not working even after copying the required DLLs.

Comment: 1) When loading a _.dll_ into a process their architectures must match (the _Python_ architecture is displayed on the 1st prompt line just after you start it), so you don't need both _x86_ and _amd64_ versions. 2) I never tried it, but I'm pretty sure that you can't handle a _C#_ _.dll_ using _ctypes_ (unless it has a _C_ interface, and for example can be used from a _C_ application). Also posting the full code and not only fragments would help. Regarding the last error, _cvextern.dll_ (**!!! or some of its dependencies !!!**) was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the libs from \libs\x64, to my is: C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop_x64-cuda 3.3.0.2826\libs\x64

Answer (score 0):

C# DLL will not be loaded using ctypes. Need to use clr.AddReference method included in python package. If python 2.7 is using need to uninstall clr package which comes as a part of 2.7 installation(This is to avoid namespace conflict). Or IronPython can be used for the same.